# Select recent n number of entries of all users from table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a below table and wants to select only last 2 entries of all users.

Source table:

```
-------------------------------------
UserId | QuizId(AID)|quizendtime(AID)|
--------------------------------------
1         10          2016-5-12
2         10          2016-5-12 
1         11          2016-6-12
2         12          2016-8-12
3         12          2016-8-12
2         13          2016-8-12
1         14          2016-9-12
3         14          2016-9-12
3         11          2016-6-12
```

Expected output is like, (should list only recent 2 quizid entries for all users)

```
-------------------------------------
UserId | QuizId(AID)|quizendtime(AID)|
--------------------------------------
1         14          2016-9-12
1         11          2016-6-12
2         13          2016-8-12
2         12          2016-8-12
3         14          2016-9-12
3         12          2016-8-12
```

Any idea's to produce this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MySQL user defined` variables you can accomplish this:

```
SELECT 
t.UserId,
t.`QuizId(AID)`,
t.`quizendtime(AID)`
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF(@sameUser = UserId, @a := @a + 1 , @a := 1) row_number,
    @sameUser := UserId
    FROM your_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 1, @sameUser := 0) var
    ORDER BY UserId , `quizendtime(AID)` DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.row_number <= 2
```

[**Working Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/946be4/1/0)

**Note:**  If you want at most `x` number of entries for each user then change the condition in where clause like below:

`WHERE t.row_number <= x`

**Explanation:**

```
SELECT 
 *,
 IF(@sameUser = UserId, @a := @a + 1 , @a := 1) row_number,
 @sameUser := UserId
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 1, @sameUser := 0) var
ORDER BY UserId , `quizendtime(AID)` DESC;
```

This query sorts all the data in ascending order of `userId` and descending order of `quizendtime(AID)`.

Now take a walk on this (multi) sorted data.

Every time you see a new `userId` assign a `row_number (1)`. If you see the same user again then just increase the `row_number`.

Finally filtering only those records which are having `row_number <= 2` ensures the at most two latest entries for each user.

**EDIT:** As Gordon pointed out that the evaluation of expressions using user defined variables in `mysql` is not guaranteed to follow the same order always so based on that the above query is slightly modified:

```
SELECT 
t.UserId,
t.`QuizId(AID)`,
t.`quizendtime(AID)`
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF (
            @sameUser = UserId,
            @a := @a + 1,
            IF(@sameUser := UserId, @a := 1, @a:= 1)
        )AS row_number
    FROM your_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 1, @sameUser := 0) var
    ORDER BY UserId , `quizendtime(AID)` DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.row_number <= 2;
```

[**WORKING DEMO V2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/946be4/2/0)

Comment: This is awesome.. Working Perfectly what i expected.. I tried to achieve this output by creating temp tables and with simple Joins.. can u please suggest any logic to get this output by using temp tables?(I got my problem solved, this is only for my understanding purpose)

Comment: I can see same result is produced without cross join, what will happen if i remove the cross join?

Comment: How did u modify the query leaving the cross join part?

Comment: Anyone reading this answer:  See my answer below.  This is not guaranteed to work because a variable is being assigned and used in different expressions.

Answer (score 1):

User-defined variables are the key to the solution.  But, it is very important to have all the variable assignments in a single expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select` -- and, in fact, sometimes processes them in different orders.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@u = UserId, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := UserId, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
       from t cross join
            (select @u := -1, @rn := 0) params
       order by UserId, quizendtime desc
      ) t
where rn <= 2;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, It would be helpful if you explain why we need cross join in the query... without that cross join above query is working fine.

Comment: @prababuddy . . . If you remove the `cross join` then the query will fail.  You need some way to connect the two items in the `from` clause . . . unless you initialize the variables some other way.  Choosing not to initialize the variables seems a wee bit dangerous, but is okay if they don't already have values.